# image fixed position not returning when side bar is closing

Tags: javascript, html, css, fixed, sidebar

I have a background picture with fixed position.
I also have a left side bar navigation that can open / close which move all the screen to the side (CSS only)
I can't find why after I open the side bar and close it the picture is not returning to full screen and I get this white strike on the right side (image attached)
After I scroll a bit the picture returning to look ok.

The CSS code for the background picture:

```
background: url(../img/plane-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

The CSS for the side bar (just the things that relevante):

```
.navigation-2 {
    /* critical sizing and position styles */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}


/* Site Wrapper - Everything that isn't navigation */
.site-wrap {
    /* Critical position and size styles */
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;

}

/* Nav Trigger */

label[for="nav-trigger"] {
    position: fixed;
    left: 15px;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 2;

}

/* Make the Magic Happen */
.nav-trigger + label, .site-wrap {
    transition: left 0.2s;
}

.nav-trigger:checked + label {
    left: 215px;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap {
    left: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #233374;
}
```

The html code for the navigation:

```
<!--<nav>-->
<ul class="navigation-2">
    <img src="img/fc-logo-white.png" width="100px">
    <li class="nav-item-2"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item-2"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item-2"><a href="#">Our Companies</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item-2"><a href="#">Career</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item-2"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
<label for="nav-trigger"></label>

<!--</nav>-->
```

The bug that appear after closing the side bar:

[image: The bug that appear after closing the side bar - image]

Would appreciate any help!
Thanks,
Shir

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see the website itself.

Comment: Important to say that when I remove the fixed position it all working just fine (but I like the fixed position style)! thanks!

Comment: It's not online yet... :/

Comment: Then please post your html code too.

Comment: There isn't much we can analyze with navigation code only. I would say upload your page online somewhere, so we can see and test it at a real time.

Comment: @ShirCohen You should upload your code somewhere i think, it's hard to analyze it with this bit of code. One thing i could think of that maybe the fixed position of the bg image is the reason, try giving it background: url(../img/plane-bg.jpg) no-repeat top center;... anyway if it does not work we need more code

Comment: Ye I know it is the reason.. just don't know why. I will update the code somewhere :)